# Successive Shortest Paths vs Ford–Fulkerson

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, max-flow

Can someone explain how exactly Successive Shortest Paths (SSP) is a generalization of the Ford–Fulkerson algorithm? I've found this stated in a few papers and websites as well as the Wikipedia page for the Minimum-cost flow problem. But none of them go any further than that statement or explain how exactly they differ. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't cross-post (it is better suited, IMO, on [cs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49431/successive-shortest-paths-vs-ford-fulkerson), anyway), at least not without giving your reason to do so.